# What is the value of the practical ethics tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't really see the value of the "practical ethics" tag. Maybe this is a difference between philosophy in America and elsewhere, but I would understand:

applied ethics    vs.  normative ethics vs. meta-ethics

but I don't get what "practical-ethics" is supposed to mean.

Comment: I agree, it seems useless. We can go through those questions and re-tag them appropriately (3/4 are within the last 24 hrs); we do this occasionally when we notice strange tags. Just wait a bit pending some discussion from the originator, which seems to be MB. Maybe he has a valid justification.

Answer (score 1):

I had asked for an 'applied-ethics' tab to be created, in [one of my questions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/14426/is-it-possible-to-act-unethically-against-oneself). In response, @MoziburUllah created the 'practical-ethics' tab, which was supposed to fill that need (see first comment there). Feel free to ask this user what the rationale was behind 'practical-ethics' vs. 'applied-ethics' (I assume it's a regional thing), but I very much think that applied ethics should exist as a tab, as it is a recognized class in most higher ed philosophy departments, and is well recognized as a subcategory by encyclopedias and journals, etc.

Comment: 'Applied ethics' seems like it'd be a better term. I notice we have a lot of questions with the [tag:social-ethics] tag too. Perhaps we should move those to the 'applied ethics' tag, unless we plan on having [all the other sub-categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applied_ethics) as well.

Comment: @stoicfury personally agree on both accounts. I wasn't necessarily defending the practical-ethics tab, merely explaining it's origin and that it's usefulness was meant to be by being used as applied-ethics would be.